# JavaScript Onclick Event doing nothing

Tags: javascript, html, image, button, onclick

I am trying to make images do some events using JavaScript. I run the html and clicking the images seems to do nothing. If anyone is able to help me out here, I'd be happy, thanks.

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>The Cafe of Pog</title>

<body>
    <h1>Pog Cafe</h1>
    <h2>Select an item!</h2>
    <script src = "js/pogCafe.js"></script>
    <img id = "cake" src = "images/cake.jpg">
    <img id = "soda" src = "images/soda.png">
    <img id = "burger" src = "images/burger.png">
</body>
</head>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
itemAmount();
function itemAmount() {
    const itemAmount = parseInt(prompt("How many items did you order?"));
    pogCafe(itemAmount);
}

function pogCafe(itemAmount) {
        const burger = document.getElementById("burger");
        const cake = document.getElementById("cake");
        const soda = document.getElementById("soda");
    let loop;
    let total = 0;
    for (loop = 0; loop < itemAmount;) {
        burger.onclick = function burgerClick() {
            const burgerPrice = 2.50;
            total = total + burgerPrice;
            loop++;
        }
        cake.onclick = function cakeClick() {
            const cakePrice = 1.50;
            total = total + cakePrice;
            loop++;
        }
        soda.onclick = function sodaClick(){
            const sodaPrice = 1.00
            total = total + sodaPrice;
            loop++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: your for loop is going to run infinetly as you dont increment the loop counter outside of the event callbacks

Comment: Why are the onClick functions in a loop?

Comment: They are in a loop because I only want the user to click on the items that many times, so if the user has 3 items, I only want them to click three times.

Comment: What is supposed to be happening here? If I say that I want 3 items, then what? What is supposed to happen when I click an image?

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the `prompt`?

Comment: Your logic doesn't make sense. Please explain the "flow" of this code... First, you ask how many items I want and, let's say I answer 3. Then what is supposed to happen next? What if I then click the soda image?

Comment: If you want 3 items, you are able to click on any of the images three times, that's what I want it to do

Comment: So what is the purpose of the `prompt`? If I want 3 sodas, I'll just click the soda image 3 times, right?

Comment: If you click on the soda image, the price gets added to the total. After the loop is over, you get your final bill.

Comment: Yeah, if you ordered 3 sodas, you click on it three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your HTML is invalid as you have the `body` element nested within the `head` element. Also, by having your `script` tag before the elements within the `body`, it will execute before those items exist within the DOM. Instead move the `script` to just before the closing `body` tag. Also, set up your events using the modern standard of `.addEventListener()` instead of `.onclick` so that you can take advantage of a more robust event handling framework.

Now there is no need for a `prompt` or a loop here. All you need to do is add the clicked item's price to the previous total and update that to be the new total. In fact, your code wasn't causing an image to be clicked on a certain number of times, it was causing a `click` event handler to be configured a certain number of times.

There are a couple of things that you could do to reduce the repetitiveness of the code below and reduce the number of event handlers being set up, but to keep it simpler to understand, I've left it un-optimized.

```js
// Get references to the elements you'll work with over and
// over just once, not every time the function runs
const burger = document.getElementById("burger");
const cake = document.getElementById("cake");
const soda = document.getElementById("soda");
const output = document.getElementById("output");

// And set up values that will need to be used
// over and over just once as well.
const burgerPrice = 2.50;
const cakePrice = 1.50;
const sodaPrice = 1.00;

// Set up event handlers the modern way, not with .onclick
burger.addEventListener("click", burgerClick);
cake.addEventListener("click", cakeClick);
soda.addEventListener("click", sodaClick);
    
// All you need to do here is add the clicked item's price
// to the previously displayed total
function burgerClick() {
  output.textContent = +output.textContent + burgerPrice;
}   

function cakeClick() {
  output.textContent = +output.textContent  + cakePrice;
}  

function sodaClick() {
  output.textContent = +output.textContent  + sodaPrice;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Cafe of Pog</title>
<!-- You didnt' have the closing head tag in the right place. -->    
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pog Cafe</h1>
    <h2>Select an item!</h2>

    <img id = "cake" src = "images/cake.jpg">
    <img id = "soda" src = "images/soda.png">
    <img id = "burger" src = "images/burger.png">
    
    <div>Your total is: <span id="output"></span></div>
    
    <!-- The script should be included just before the
         closing body tag so that by the time it is reached
         all the HTML will have been parsed into memory. -->
    <script src = "js/pogCafe.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it is just, bad. You attach event-listeners in a for loop? Don't do that.
Below is the solution:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>The Cafe of Pog</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pog Cafe</h1>
    <h2>Select an item!</h2>
    <img id = "cake" src = "images/cake.jpg">
    <img id = "soda" src = "images/soda.png">
    <img id = "burger" src = "images/burger.png">  

    <script src = "js/pogCafe.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
let total = 0;  
  
const burgerPrice = 2.50;  
const burger = document.getElementById("burger");  
burger.onclick = function burgerClick() {  
    const amount = parseInt(prompt("How many burgers did you order?"));  
    total = total + burgerPrice*amount;  
}  

const cakePrice = 1.50;  
const cake = document.getElementById("cake");  
cake.onclick = function burgerClick() {  
    const amount = parseInt(prompt("How many cakes did you order?"));  
    total = total + cakePrice*amount;  
}  
  
const sodaPrice = 1.00;  
const soda = document.getElementById("soda");  
soda.onclick = function burgerClick() {  
    const amount = parseInt(prompt("How many sodas did you order?"));  
    total = total + sodaPrice*amount;  
}
```

Comment: I try that, and clicking the images still does nothing, is it a problem with my HTML?

Comment: Now that i noticed: move the `<script.../>` part in the end, just before the `</body>`

Comment: The error I get is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at pogCafe.js:5"

Comment: The loop counter is meant to add up by one if you click on an image

Comment: Oh man....is your HTML wrong or is it just a typo? Your `</head>` is in the wrong place

Comment: Dotnex, are you able to send your html as an answer? Thanks.